# Where does the value $ds_content come from in display suite templates?

Tags: 7, display-suite

After updating to the newest version of display suite I noticed that in display suite ds-reset.tpl.php the value for $ds_content is now blank.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Display Suite reset template.
 */
?>
<?php print $ds_content; ?>
<?php if (!empty($drupal_render_children)): ?>
  <?php print $drupal_render_children ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Where is this value assigned so I can better troubleshoot what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's set in `ds/includes/ds.registry.inc` in `_ds_ds_layout_info()` which implements a hook `hook_ds_layout_info`